# Static assert the size of a template type on instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, static-assert

I want to check the size of the following structure on instantiation with `static_assert` to constrain that the unnamed `struct` is tightly packed, thus the size of `A` is equivalent to `sizeof(T) * 3`.

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
   union
   {
      struct { T a, b, c; };
      T arr[3];
   };
};
```

This could be done with

```
static_assert(sizeof(A<T>) == sizeof(T) * 3, "hey something went wrong");
```

**However**

- since `A<T>` is still an incomplete type inside its class definition, putting the above `static_assert` into the class definition is not an option
- `static_assert` with `sizeof` doesn't evaluate inside un-instantiated functions in all compilers (like Clang), so putting it into a dummy member function is not an option
- putting `static_assert` to a constructor or destructor would be a solution, but in the above example no user-defined constructor exists (think about *aggregates*), furthermore imagine the case of multiple constructors, where I would avoid performing the assertion in all of them
- inheriting `A` from an another struct, and performing `static_assert` on that in the definition of `A` would be a solution, but I want to keep the struct simple, without messing with helper structures

Any other solution I'm missing?

**I decided to undelete this question and keep it open for possible solutions in the future.**

Comment: Of course `sizeof` isn't allowed on incomlete types but when you instantiate   your structure the type of `T` can't be incomplete, otherwise it simply wouldn't compile, with or without `sizeof`

Comment: You can't create a union without knowing the sizes of the types, so you need the type to be complete anyway. So, the first solution should be fine.

Comment: There is still the destructor but (as for constructor) you may break some properties (aggregate, trivially destructible). And you have to enable move/copy constructor/assignment.

Comment: @OMGtechy No, class A inside its class definition is still incomplete, so the first solution won't compile.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername yes, but no one talks about that T is incomplete. A<T> is inside its class definition.

Comment: Why not use `pragma pack(1)` to ensure packing?

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername I use it, but some compiler simply ignores it. So this is more about checking.

Answer (score 0):

One special member function (almost) guaranteed to be instantiated is the destructor:

```
~A() noexcept { static_assert(sizeof(A<T>) == sizeof(T) * 3, "hey something went wrong"); }
```

Comment: Yes, but as @Jarod42 also stated in his comment, that will break aggregate rule and trivially default destructability.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace my_private_impl{
    struct impl_tag{};
    template <typename T,typename tag>
    struct A_impl{
        static_assert(is_same<tag,impl_tag>{}(),"you evil cheater");
        union{
            struct { T a, b, c; };
            T arr[3];
        };
    };
};

template<typename T>
using A=std::enable_if_t<
    sizeof(my_private_impl::A_impl<T,my_private_impl::impl_tag>) == sizeof(T) * 3,
    my_private_impl::A_impl<T,my_private_impl::impl_tag>
>;
```